# scatterplot/linear regression in manim 0.12.0

Tags: python, linear-regression, scatter-plot, manim

i'm pretty new to manim and looking to create an animated regression analysis (i know).

Now, i've gotten everything to run and made a decent looking numberplane and line, but i can't for the life of me plot the datapoints as dots.

**i have the datapoints in a csv, formatted as follows:**

Data:
18166, 578,
20769, 658,
4226, 136,
2904, 95,

**and run the following code to get the coords:**

```
def get_coords_from_csv(Filename):
    import csv
    coords = []
    with open(f'{Filename}.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
         reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
         for row in reader:
             x,y = row
             coord = [float(x),float(y)]
             coords.append(coord)
    csvFile.close()
    return coords
```

Now, my question is: how do i convert these coords to points on my numberplane?

So far, i've scoured the internet to no avail, and although theoremofbeethoven did a video (customgraphs) surrounding the topic.. most of that code is no longersupported in 0.12.0.

currently, my graph is animated as follows:

```
class graphing(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        Simp = Text("Simple linear regression", font_size = 30, color = RED)

        plane = NumberPlane(
        x_range = [0, 30000, 5000], x_length = 10, y_range = [0, 1000, 200], 
        y_length = 7) .scale(0.7).add_coordinates()

        ylabel = Text("CoS", font_size = 20).next_to(plane, LEFT, buff = 0.3)
        xlabel = Text("Revenue", font_size = 20).next_to(plane, DOWN, buff = 0.2)

        lm = plane.plot(lambda x : -0.3511 + 0.0318 * x, x_range = [0, 30000], color 
        = WHITE)
        func_label = MathTex(r"fX= \theta_{0}+\theta_{1}\*x").scale(0.6).next_to(lm, 
        RIGHT, buff=0.5)

        self.play(Create(Simp), run_time = 0.7)
        self.play(Simp.animate.to_edge(UP))
        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(plane))self.play(Create(lm), run_time = 1)
        self.play(Create(VGroup(ylabel, xlabel, func_label), run_time = 
        1))self.wait(2)
```

which works fine as is, but i really want to include the scattered dots

Thanks a bunch to whoever can help me, and sorry for the long post! i've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and i'm starting to lose sleep over it.

Comment: if you use `with open()` then you don't need `close()`

Comment: you could create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it.